# Find the coordinates of the points where the curve$ y=x^3-5x^2+2x+8 $cuts the y-axis and the x-axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I have obtained three points where it cuts the $x$-axis because I followed the process for quadratic equations,not cubic. Could someone explain it in detail?

Thanks to everyone who takes the time to answer.

Comment: Easier method: Step one, try to find a root by inspection.  Common, easy to calculate guesses are $0,1,-1$.  If you get lucky enough to have correctly guessed a root, perform polynomial long division to write it in the form $(ax^2+bx+c)(x+d)$.  Find the roots for the quadratic factor as normal.  Harder method: apply [Cardano's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) (*very rarely taught*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a good look ,find out that 
  $$x=-1 \to f(-1)=0\\x=2 \to f(2)=0$$ so you can divide $x^3-5x^2+2x+8 $ to $x+1$ or $x-2$ then you will have :$$f(x)=(x+1)(x-2)(x-4) $$ so $x=-1,2,4$ cuts $x$-axis
and when you put $x=0 \to f(0)=+8$ so $y$-axis cuts in $(0,8)$